# problem accessing wallet

Tags: cryptography, wallet.dat

I have a 2011 wallet.dat created in version 0.4.0 it accepts my password normally.  but when putting in the current version of bitcoin core it doesn't work can you help me?

If I enter any other (not correct) password, it doesn't. I can enter 10000 incorrect passwords and the above error message does not appear.

At first I thought that the password(s) I was using were not correct, but then I made an observation, that only when I type only a specific password do I get this message in the popup:

```
assertion failed
program: C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe
File: wallet/crypter.cpp, line 205 
expression false
Runtime error
program: C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe
```

Comment: Remember: Bitcoin doesn't have staff. This website is not run by the people who created Bitcoin. This site is a coomunity-run self help question and answer website where people like you answer other people's questions.

Comment: I only have this password and it works in version 0.4.0 in current versions of the error

Comment: Perhaps you could [update your question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/posts/114374/edit) to add a list of the exact steps you took and the exact error message?

Comment: If I enter any other (not correct) password, it doesn't.  I can enter 10000 incorrect passwords and the above error message does not appear.

Comment: At first I thought that the password(s) I was using were not correct, but then I made an observation, that only when I type only a specific password do I get this message in the popup:


 assertion failed<<<

 program: C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe<<<

 File: wallet/crypter.cpp, line 205<<<

 expression false<<<


 Runtime error<<<

 program: C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe